# how to access array of dictionaries in UITableView have multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm developing  app and i have Back-end API return this data

.... [removed]

I create tableView with 5 sections , as following

```
   // Number of rows each section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if section == 0 {
            if let Sunday =  DataService.DataServiceInstance.ArrayForDay("Sunday")
            {
                if let ArrayPerDay:NSArray = Sunday as NSArray{

                    return ArrayPerDay.count
                }

            }


        }

        if section == 1 {

            if let Monday =  DataService.DataServiceInstance.ArrayForDay("Monday")
            {
                if let ArrayPerDay:NSArray = Monday as NSArray{

                    return ArrayPerDay.count
                }


            }

        }

        if section == 2 {

            if let Tuesday =  DataService.DataServiceInstance.ArrayForDay("Tuesday")
            {
                if let ArrayPerDay:NSArray = Tuesday as NSArray{

                    return ArrayPerDay.count
                }

            }

        }

        if section == 3 {

            if let Wednesday =  DataService.DataServiceInstance.ArrayForDay("Wednesday")
            {
                if let ArrayPerDay:NSArray = Wednesday as NSArray{

                    return ArrayPerDay.count
                }
            }

        }

        if section == 4 {

            if let Thursday =  DataService.DataServiceInstance.ArrayForDay("Thursday")
            {
                if let ArrayPerDay:NSArray = Thursday as NSArray{

                    return ArrayPerDay.count
                }
            }

        }

        return 0
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView)->Int
    {
        return 5

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 60.0
    }
```

Then i create a function to count total rows for each days

```
func ArrayForDay(dayAsk:String)->NSArray?{


    var TimeTableDic = [NSDictionary]()

    if let FirstArray  = ArrayOfRegistredModules  {

        for firstArrayItem in FirstArray {

            if let timetableArray:NSArray = firstArrayItem["Timetable"] as? NSArray
            {

                for itemInTimeTable in timetableArray{

                    if itemInTimeTable["Day"] as? String == dayAsk{

                        if let appendData = itemInTimeTable as? NSDictionary{

                            TimeTableDic.append(appendData)
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

i tried like this

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {

            // Get Sunday Timetable
            if let sunDayModel = DataService.DataServiceInstance.LoadData[0]["ModulesRegistered"] as? NSArray {

                for itemInArray in sunDayModel {

                    for getTimeTable in itemInArray["Timetable"] as! NSArray {

                        if getTimeTable["Day"] as! String == "Sunday" {

                            print(getTimeTable)
                        }
                        //print(getTimeTable)

                    }

                }

            }

        }else if indexPath.section == 1{

            // Get Sunday Timetable
            if let sunDayModel = DataService.DataServiceInstance.LoadData[0]["ModulesRegistered"] as? NSArray {

                for itemInArray in sunDayModel {

                    for getTimeTable in itemInArray["Timetable"] as! NSArray {

                        if getTimeTable["Day"] as! String == "Monday" {

                            print(getTimeTable)
                        }
                        //print(getTimeTable)

                    }

                }

            }


        }else if indexPath.section == 2 {

            print("Tusday")

        }
```

and the result of this is repeating the section index as much row it has for example if we have 3 rows in section 0 i will get 
0 
0 
0

i want to show Timetable for each Day Example

Sunday section should only display Sunday timeTable , i can show the number of rows in each section but i don't know how to create cell for each section .

Thank You .

Comment: When posting a question try to make a simplified example of the issue. Putting all this code makes the question harder to read and thus there will be less answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

its been messy in swift to parse JSON data,
i would personally suggest you to convert your section data and convert your row array according to section you got.

```
let moduleArray:NSArry = yourJSONDict.valueforKey("ModulesRegistered") as! NSArray
```

moduleArray will be your section data source

now in cellar row at index path

```
let sectionDict:NSDictionary = moduleAray[indexpath.section] as! NSDictionary

let rowArray:NSArray = sectionDict.valueforKey("Timetable") as! NSArray
```

now you have array of your time table and you can loop through it or i would personally suggest NSPredict to do so..

The snippet above is just logic how can you achive what you want you should not copy paste directly...

Happy coding...
have a good day ahead.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more , i tried  your logic but i can't  understand how i can get sections of days according to my data .

Comment: you have row array..now you have to predicate with the section header like

let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Day = %@", section header)

let sectionArray:NSARrry = [rowAray filterArrayWithPredicat: resultPredicate]

Comment: instead of that i would simply suggest you to change your response and get data by days and module as subarray

Comment: i can not change the API it's out of my control  , i will try to play around

Comment: ok then go with predicate , you have to loop through all the module array and use predicate for to find data with day..good luck.. let us know the result

Answer (score 0):

I Solve my problem

- I create a class to manage the data
- i create function to fetch data per day
- i create function to count how many rows for each day
- i pass functions to cell and numOfRows in tableView ,

Thanks for all .